# Is Julia `String` NUL-terminated?

Tags: julia

Is it safe to directly pass `"abc"` to a `ccall` that expects a `Ptr{Cchar}`?

I know I can use `Cstring` in the `ccall` instead, this question is more about the `String` type itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, currently `String`s in Julia are always NUL-terminated. This is intentionally not documented though, since it might change in future versions of Julia. That's why you should generally prefer to use `Cstring` explicitly whenever something expects a NUL-terminated string. This is currently just a no-op, but it should be more future-proof and I also find it more self-documenting.